# Querying Reverse ManyToMany Relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a category Model and a Product Model in my django application... the product model has a many2many field pointing to the category model... and the product model has a added field to denote when it was created.
how do i filter the categories model based on the added field value of the product?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    #this model SHOULD BE managed by the platform admin
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    items_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories_images',help_text='Generic Image describing the category very very well', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.slug)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploaded_products/', default="products/default_product.png")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name='products', blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

i want to be able to do a query for the current trending categories based on the added field of the product.

Comment: I'm not really following what you mean with *all the categories based on the created field*. Can you provide the (relevant parts of) your `Category` and `Product` model, together with some sample data and the expected outcome?

Comment: Do you mean something like you want categories which have products added in a certain time period? Please be more explicit with what you want to say.

Comment: i have uploaded the model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first look for each `Category` when was the most recent `Product` that was added with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias), or with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2). We annotate this with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Category.objects.alias(
    most_recent_change=Max('products__added')
)
```

Then we can retrieve the objects through filtering. For example if we only want to retrieve `Category`s updated in the last 24 hours, we can filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Category.objects.alias(
    most_recent_change=Max('products__added')
).filter(
    most_recent__gte=Now()-timedelta(days=1)
)
```

or we can make use of the timestamp provided by Django itself:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.db.models import Max

Category.objects.alias(
    most_recent_change=Max('products__added')
).filter(
    most_recent__gte=now()-timedelta(days=1)
)
```

Comment: i have no experience with alias, but it seems that the name most_recent_change should match the second ocurrence most_recent... do you get me? and besides i am getting an error that says ```django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types: DateTimeField, DurationField. You must set output_field.```

Comment: @BrianObot: can you please edit the question with the *full* traceback. You should use `products__added` since you specified a `related_name` for the many-to-many relation.

Comment: its worked now without an error....but the resulting queryset is empty but i have added some product within a window from 30 minutes from now..what could be the issue?

Comment: @BrianObot: and these products are linked to a category? What database are you using?

Comment: yes...i link the product to their respectives categories.. am using sqlite3. the categories do reflect on the admin site

Comment: @BrianObot: what do you get if you `print(Category.objects.aggregate(most_recent_change=Max('products__added')))` so with `.aggregate(...)` not `.annotate(...)`.

Comment: {'most_recent_change': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 11, 13, 6, 46, 320045, tzinfo=<UTC>)}

Comment: @BrianObot: what if you use Django's `now()` instead of the database's `Now()` (so the last code fragment).

Comment: ```Category.objects.alias(most_recent_change=Max('product__created')).order_by('-most_recent_change')
```

Comment: @BrianObot: yes, besides filtering, you can also order, etc. the categories by most recent change. 